# how to save settings of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Rational software Architect(RSA) which is like eclipse .Now i have done lots of settings under
windows >preferences. Now want to export this settings and then apply those settings 
directly to another instance of RSA installed on another machine.

How do i export and the import this and the import?The way to do this in eclipse will also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings are saved in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings inside your workspace. In your case copying the .metadata folder should do the work.

Comment: thanks for replyig : How can  apply same setting to another instance of eclipe running on another machine?